# Is there any way in which we can use node.js Api in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, angular-meteor, angular-fullstack

As I am an early bird to Meteor.js .So, I want to ask that can I use node API in my Meteor.js project. I got stuck in my project and didn't find anything related to this topic and I have already spent too much time for this topic.
So is there any way we can use node API?
How can we solve this issue? Any ideas are appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: can you explain using some code??

Answer (score 1):

You just use it as usual. Your code already works "inside" nodeJS, so you just its API and that's all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use node API with Meteor + angular (meteor client side) project. You have to call simple get method to access the node API.